# React, Firebase: Auth possibly failing on redirect

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication

I've got component that captures user information and posts it to firebase, when the submit button is hit. Also within this component is a function that gets all posted data, and returns only the posts made by the currently logged in user:

```
     authListener() {
        auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
          if(user){
            this.setState({
              userDetails:user
            },
            () =>
            firebase.firestore().collection('gig-listing').onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
              let filteredGigs = querySnapshot.docs.filter(snapshot => {
                return snapshot.data().user === this.state.userDetails.uid
              })
              this.setState({
                filterGigs: filteredGigs
              })
            })
            ) //end of set state
          } else {
            this.setState({
              userDetails:null
            })
            console.log('no user signed in')
          }
        })
      }
```

This function works and displays what it should. However, when the submit function (in the same component) is executed, it should redirect to another page, but instead I get no render, and the error
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of null`  
When I refresh the page however, it shows the correct page.

What this is basically saying is that, on redirect, `this.state.userDetails.uid` evaluates to null, even though I'm signed in at the time. Any ideas why this is happening and any potential solutions?

Here's the component in it's entirety:

```
import React from "react";
import Header from "./Header";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import axios from "axios";
import  firebase from 'firebase'
import { auth } from 'firebase/app'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import UniqueVenueListing from './UniqueVenueListing'

const StyledButton = withStyles({
  root: {
    background: '#54ADA6',
    borderRadius: 3,
    border: 0,
    color: 'white',
    height: 30,
    padding: '0 30px',
    marginRight: '1px'
    
  },
  label: {
    textTransform: 'capitalize',
  },
})(Button);



    class GigRegister extends React.Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          name: "",
          venue: "",
          time: "",
          date: "",
          genre: "",
          tickets: "",
          price: "",
          venueWebsite: "",
          bandWebsite:"",
          userDetails: {},
          filterGigs: [],
          isLoggedIn:false,
          currentToken:{}
        };
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
      }

      handleChange(e) {
        this.setState({
          [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
        });
      }

      handleClick() {
        console.log("handle click reached");
        auth()
          .signOut()
          .then(() => {
            console.log("Successfully signed out");
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
          });
      }

      authListener() {
        auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
          if(user){
            console.log(`this is the user: ${user.uid}`)
            this.setState({
              userDetails:user
            },
            () =>
            firebase.firestore().collection('gig-listing').onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
              let filteredGigs = querySnapshot.docs.filter(snapshot => {
                return snapshot.data().user === this.state.userDetails.uid
              })
              this.setState({
                filterGigs: filteredGigs
              })
            })
            ) //end of set state
          } else {
            this.setState({
              userDetails:null
            })
            console.log('no user signed in')
          }
        })
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        this.authListener();
      }


      handleSubmit(e) {
        
        let user = this.state.userDetails.uid;
        const gigData = {
          name: this.state.name,
          venue: this.state.venue,
          time: this.state.time,
          date: this.state.date,
          genre: this.state.genre,
          tickets: this.state.tickets,
          price: this.state.price,
          venueWebsite: this.state.venueWebsite,
          bandWebsite: this.state.bandWebsite,
          user: user
        };

        auth()
          .currentUser.getIdToken()
          .then(function (token) {
            axios(
              "https://us-central1-gig-fort.cloudfunctions.net/api/createGigListing",
              {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                  "content-type": "application/json",
                  Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
                },
                data: gigData,
              }
            );
          })
          .then((res) => {
            this.props.history.push("/Homepage");
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.error(err);
          });
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <div className="gig-register">
            <Header />
            <div className="heading-container">
              <h1>Venue Dashboard</h1> <br></br>
              {this.state.userDetails ? (
                <h3>You are signed in as {this.state.userDetails.email}</h3>
              ) : null}
              <div className="gig-reg-buttons">
                {this.state.userDetails ? (
                  <StyledButton onClick={this.handleClick}>Sign out </StyledButton>
                ) : (
                  <Link to="/" style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>
                    <StyledButton>Sign In</StyledButton>
                  </Link>
                )}
                <Link to="/Homepage" style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>
                <StyledButton>Go to gig listings</StyledButton>
                </Link>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="handle-gigs">
              <div className="reg-gig-input">
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                  <h3>Register a gig</h3>
                  <br></br>
                  <TextField
                    placeholder="Event name"
                    id="name"
                    name="name"
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                  />
                  <TextField
                    placeholder="Time"
                    type="time"
                    label="Enter start time"
                    id="time"
                    name="time"
                    InputLabelProps={{
                      shrink: true,
                    }}
                    inputProps={{
                      step: 300, // 5 min
                    }}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                  />
                  <TextField
                    id="date"
                    label="Select date"
                    type="date"
                    InputLabelProps={{
                      shrink: true,
                    }}
                    onChange={(e) => {
                      this.setState({ date: e.target.value });
                    }}
                  />
                  <TextField
                    placeholder="Genre"
                    id="genre"
                    name="genre"
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                  />
                  <TextField
                    placeholder="Band website"
                    id="bandWebsite"
                    name="bandWebsite"
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                  />
                  <TextField
                    placeholder= "Link to ticketing agent"
                    id="tickets"
                    name="tickets"
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                  />
                  <TextField
                    placeholder="Price"
                    id="price"
                    name="price"
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                  />
                  <TextField
                    placeholder="Venue website"
                    id="venueWebsite"
                    name="venueWebsite"
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                  />
                  <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
                </form>
              </div>
              <div className="manage-gigs">
                <h3 className="manage-gig">Manage your gigs</h3>
                <br></br>
                {this.state.userDetails ? (
                  <UniqueVenueListing gigList={this.state.filterGigs} />
                ) : (
                  <h2>no gigs to show</h2>
                )}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        );
      }
    }
    
    export default GigRegister
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the data is loaded from Firestore asynchronously, there is no guarantee that the user is still signed in by the time your `filter` method runs.

---

If you want to continue using the user that was signed in when the `onAuthStateChanged` triggered, use the `user` parameter that was passed in, instead of the value from the state:

```
  if(user){
    console.log(`this is the user: ${user.uid}`)
    this.setState({
      userDetails:user
    },
    () =>
    firebase.firestore().collection('gig-listing').onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
      let filteredGigs = querySnapshot.docs.filter(snapshot => {
        return snapshot.data().user === user.uid
      })
```

The `user` variable in here is guaranteed to still have the correct value, as it is defined within the same scope. The `state` doesn't have such a guarantee as it is globally shared.

---

Alternatively if you want to use the user from the state, check whether it still has a value once you get the data from the database:

```
  if(user){
    console.log(`this is the user: ${user.uid}`)
    this.setState({
      userDetails:user
    },
    () =>
    firebase.firestore().collection('gig-listing').onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
      if (this.state.userDetails) {
        let filteredGigs = querySnapshot.docs.filter(snapshot => {
          return snapshot.data().user === this.state.userDetails.uid
        })
      }
      else {
        console.log("User no longer signed in when database returned results, skipping filtering...");
      }
```